# control move in canvas with alignmentrular affect

Tags: wpf, controls, drag

I am working on a form designer application in wpf. A functionality to show a alignment rular at runtime as in WPF designtime has to implement. Please suggest me the approach. Or anyone who done it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm drawing a lines with the respective element (Control). As i will have four possible controls to which we have to draw measurement line.

Step 1. I have all children of controls with its location in a list, which i have prepared on drawing controls at run-time at Mouse move event.

Step 2: I calculate the closest cords difference with respective controls. and drawn line for for that points.